# Detecting when UISearchController Appears in Navigation Item in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

I'm implementing UISearchController as part of the navigation item in iOS 11. This, in general, works fine. But I need to know when the searchBar is shown or hidden automatically via scrolling. None of the delegate methods in UISearchController or UISearchBar provide this information. The isActive property in UISearchController is only true when the searchBar gets focus (first responder).

The only way I've found is to use KVO on the height searchBar frame but that seams rather extreme for something like this.

Related to my requirement is also the ability to programmatically hide the searchBar (as if the user had scrolled up). The only way I've found to do this is by setting the navigation item's UISearchController property to nil but that also seems rather extreme.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is adding the `searchBar` inside the scroll view (table view) on top of the cell(s):

[image]

And you can identify searchBar shown or hidden using offset value. This is not perfect way to do it but it helps to achieve your need.

Comment: But I don't think that will integrate it into the navigation bar, right? So, I would loose one of the nice iOS 11 features. I want to be able to do detect it when use in the nav item (as the title of my question states).

Comment: Sorry but you don't get the searchBar integrated into the nav bar with TableView option. The TableView option is basically the old style of bringing up a searchBar. Besides, having to check the offset is not much different than having to check the frame's height. But I do appreciate your input.

Comment: I appreciate your comment but considering your question, there is no such delegate methods available which will tell you directly while show/hidden searchBar. So I have Just given you alternative way to do it. As I don’t know your priority for nav bar.

Comment: You can set bounty to your question. You may get multiple answers which may help you to do so.